# Read in first 3 characters of each line in file into an array of Strings

Tags: c

I have to read in the first three characters in each line in a file into an array of Strings. Why isn't this working?

```
int getName(FILE *inFile, char name[MAX][4]){

    char *line = NULL;
    char *word = NULL;
    int counter=0;  

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),inFile) != NULL){

        sscanf(line, "%c%c%c\n", word);
        strcpy(name[counter], word);    
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `fgets` call results in undefined behaviour because you pass a pointer to 1 `char`, but say it's `sizeof(char*)` (4 to 8 bytes on most platforms) bytes (`char`s). A quick fix would be to have a fixed size array that you expect to be big enough for a whole line and pass that instead:

```
char line[512];

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, inFile) != NULL){
```

Your `sscanf` call expects exactly 3 characters, followed by a new-line. If there are more, but you only want the first 3 you need to get rid of the `\n` in the format string. Also, you need to provide 3 `char*`s for the 3 `%c` specifiers and those need to point to allocated memory, not `NULL`. Alternatively, you could specify a string of 3 characters and have it placed into `name` immediately:

```
sscanf(line, "%3s", name[counter]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This line: `sscanf(line, "%c%c%c\n", word);`
This is requesting to read 3 single character values an place each one in its own variable, however you are only passing one variable in (word). You need to have 3. So what is happening is that scan is writing the second two characters to addresses in memory pointed by whatever stuff happens to be on the stack after the `word` parameter.

I've modified your routine slightly to resolve this issue.

```
int getName(FILE *inFile, char name[MAX][4]){

    char *line = NULL;
    char word [4] = {0};
    int counter=0;

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),inFile) != NULL){

        sscanf(line, "%c%c%c\n", &word[0], &word[1], &word[2]);
        strcpy(name[counter], word);
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option of a function that reads the first 3 chars of every line in a file

```
int getName(FILE *inFile, char name[MAX][4]){
    int counter = 0;
    int ch;
    int i = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(inFile)) != EOF) {

        char word[3];
        if (i < 3) {
            word[i++] = ch;
            if (i == 3 || ch == '\n') {
                if (counter < MAX) {
                    strcpy(name[counter], word);
                    counter++;
                } else { break; }
            }
        }
        if (ch == '\n') { i = 0; }
    }  
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: I have tested the function so if you still have problem with it, it might be how you pass name[MAX][4]